# Can I run two FTP sites on one server using two different IP addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ftp, ssl, osx-server

So we currently have our FTP site running on one computer (Mac OS-X) with one IP address. We are trying to host a second FTP site running off of the same computer, but with a different IP address.

Is is possible to have two FTP's running off of the same computer/server if I have a different IP address for both FTP's?

Also, is it possible to install SSL onto a Mac OS-X?

Thirdly, is it possible to connect an API that was written in Linux to a Unix server?

Any and all insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want two FTP sites using different IP addresses? You can run multiple ftp sites using a single IP address. You just need to make use of port numbers.

Comment: I assume the only option, apart from the ISP giving you two different IP's and the one @yassarikhan786 gave would be to proxy one of the FTP servers... but that would fall on the previous comment's answer.

Comment: @yassarikhan786, my second FTP site requires FTP over SSL, and my first FTP does not. I have been told that if I add the SSL to the first FTP, it might break the FTP and screw up all of my other folders.

Comment: FTP+SSL is a travesty, getting it through firewalls/NAT is a huge PITA.  Plain FTP is evil, since it is not encrypted.  If you can avoid using either you should.  Instead strongly consider just using sftp (SSH file transfer protocol).

Comment: `Thirdly, is it possible to connect an API that was written in Linux to a Unix server?` - **Yes/Maybe/No/It depends, you haven't given enough information.**  You are also asking to many questions in a single post.  A post should have a single question, or set of very closely related questions where there will can be a single accepted answer.  This site is not a forum.

Comment: IMHO, you should use vsftpd, a Very Secure ftp Daemon, for a single site. It will not break you system. Read [here](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) some enlightening info on this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need either a second NIC or the ability to add a second IP to your current NIC. It can be done, but your FTP server will need to be configured. You will have to tell it what IP to listen to. Some FTP server software might not have this capability, so you will have to inquire with the particular software vendor.